# How to check whether my table is a Kudu table or not

Tags: impala, kudu

---

I am working on a project that requires update on Kudu table. But I do not know whether my required table is a Kudu table/Impala table as it was created by my ex-colleague. Is there any way to know what type of table it is?

Answer (score 0):

I know its a bit late but maybe someone will find it useful later on :)

You can use this:

> SHOW CREATE TABLE [database_name].table_name

For kudu tables you will find properties for kudu masters and info about kudu partitioning

Here is nice example: [Apache docs](https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_kudu.html)

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE inline_pk_rewritten;
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| result                                                                       |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| CREATE TABLE user.inline_pk_rewritten (                                      |
|   id BIGINT NOT NULL ENCODING AUTO_ENCODING COMPRESSION DEFAULT_COMPRESSION, |
|   s STRING NULL ENCODING AUTO_ENCODING COMPRESSION DEFAULT_COMPRESSION,      |
|   PRIMARY KEY (id)                                                           |
| )                                                                            |
| PARTITION BY HASH (id) PARTITIONS 2                                          |
| STORED AS KUDU                                                               |
| TBLPROPERTIES ('kudu.master_addresses'='host.example.com')                   |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Sometimes its also usefull to run describe formatted on given table, you can find some usefull informations here to

[Sample doc for describe command from Cloudera distribution](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/6/6.3/topics/impala_describe.html)